# Increase Max String Length For Options in Winform Checklist Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checklistbox

I have a winform with a checklist box.  I am populating it with some text options.  I noticed that the max string length for an option is 25 characters; any text above 25 characters is being truncated.

Is there a way to expand the the string size for an option in a checklist box?

For reference, I am using Visual Studio.

Edit:  I wrote wpf, but in reality it's winform.

Comment: You just need to set the size (`Width` property) of the checkbox appropriately. You didn't bother to show any code, so it's not possible to provide an actual answer that shows you what you need to change.

Comment: Is `CheckListBox` a WPF Extended ToolKit control?

Comment: Doesn't seem to wrap for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such kind of limitation.
The size of the parent container of your checklistbox might be the guilty party.